# MPMoviePlayer done button action can not work

Tags: ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a video list, and I want show video player by full screen when user click the list item , so I add the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath moethod:

```
   [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] addSubview:vc.view];
```

in video controller , I add the NSNotificationCenter code in view didload and add the action code

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:moviePlayer
    selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
    object:nil];

-(void)doneButtonClick:(NSNotification *)Notification{
    NSLog(@"...............doneButtonClick....... \n ");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];

    [moviePlayer stop];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

When I click the done button, it can not work, But If I change the

```
   [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] addSubview:vc.view];
```

to

```
   [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] setRootViewController:vc];
```

The done button can work normally, who can tell me the reason and the right way to add MPMovieController to window with full screen, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do it myself and it works well for me

```
[self presentModalViewController:movieController animated:YES];
    // Listen for interesting movie player notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedPlayback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```